# 2 Same HTTP Requests Give Different Results?

Tags: java, google-chrome, http, web-services, postman

What differentiate these 2 requests that cause them to have different results/responses from the server although they should be the same ?

1. Request initiated by Chrome after a simple
   click/navigation(successful, response code is 302)
2. I simply copied
   that request as a curl and imported it to Postman and then postman
   hanged

I did the same with Java - HttpUrlConnection(mimicking all the request headers and cookies like Chrome sent), but it hanged and waited forever. Is this simply because of the server logic that doesn't accept non-browser client ?

Here are the steps that I tried:

```
1. Visited this link: https://www.tokopedia.com/p/handphone-tablet/handphone
2. I opened the inspector and opened the Network - All tab
3. I clicked one of the products
4. I clicked the top request from the Network - All tab
5. I copied it as cURL bash
6. I imported it to Postman
7. I ran that request
8. Postman hanged
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem might even go deeper than what the other answers say.

So neither the User-Agent request header nor telnet might solve that problem (unless you initialize the TLS handshake also with telnet MANUALLY, but that is near impossible to complete).

## TLS fingerprinting

If the connection is an SSL/TLS connection, the server could detect which algorithm is used to generate keys, and most applications have their specific signature / cipher.

So only by the TLS handshake alone you can tell Chrome from Postman or FireFox or Java. Java usually - unless a JVM implementation REALLY wants to go off-road - has the same signature across all platforms, using the same cipher/algorithm across all implementations.

<strike>I am sorry I cannot properly recall the name of this technique. The first project I know that published this is called something like "A3" or "S3".</strike>  Salesforce published an article about `JA3` analysis. They describe the technique and show a list of signatures and applications so you can guesstimate what app you're talking to, without the need to even decrypt the data: https://engineering.salesforce.com/tls-fingerprinting-with-ja3-and-ja3s-247362855967

## My Solution

I had that same problem too, wanted to scan the NVidia or AMD servers for graphics card availability. Did not work from Java, so after a lot of research, finding the project mentioned above, I simply used Selenium to control FireFox and that got the proper server responses and I achieved my goal this way.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to be sure that the *exact* same data is sent is to manually send it yourself through something like telnet. I had a similar problem once- it turned out that the browser was sending the data in one big chunk, while my code was sending it line-by-line. No site should have this problem, but it's possible that it exists.

Answer (score 0):

The server might be checking for [User-Agent request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) and will block traffic that does not originate from a browser. Try setting the header in [curl](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/curl-set-user-agent-command-linux-unix/) or your Java Code to a value corresponding to (any) browser. I've encountered such behavior on some e-shops and commercial websites.

Comment: I have set that in Java and when I copied that request from Chrome to cURL, all the headers and cookies were already set according to the original request.(22 request headers in total).

Comment: When I had that problem I needed to scrape a web page using Python requests and Beautiful Soup. I remember having to try multiple User Agent (UA) strings because the server was rejecting older Mozilla UA and the connection was hanging as you described. Newer Mozilla UA eventually worked. But you said your Chrome worked all right with that site and if all headers were copied, it should work with other client. Maybe check if the UA is being set correctly on https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent Sorry, don't have any better ideas.